# Accessing attribute of an element inside a template and use it in other element in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

Is there a way to do the following

```
<span data-value="apple" #customSpan>
   <span *ngIf="customSpan.magic.moreMagic === 'apple'"> OMG! Its an Apple:)<span>
   <span *ngIf="customSpan.magic.moreMagic != 'apple'"> Oh No! its not an Apple :( <span>
<span>
```

whats that magic/moreMagics...? or is it not possible to do this way.
Open to other ways too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any attribute can be accessed from within the template.

```
<span foo="apple" #customSpan>
   <span *ngIf="customSpan.attributes['foo'].value === 'apple'"> OMG! Its an Apple:)<span>
   <span *ngIf="customSpan.attributes['foo'].value != 'apple'"> Oh No! its not an Apple :( <span>
<span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this.

```
<span data-value="apple" #customSpan>
   <span *ngIf="customSpan.dataset.value === 'apple'"> OMG! Its an Apple:)<span>
   <span *ngIf="customSpan.dataset.value != 'apple'"> Oh No! its not an Apple :( <span>
<span>
```

Here `value` is not the default property that exists on `dataset` object, but it is a part of `data-value`. So if use something like `data-color` then extract it like `customSpan.dataset.color`.